# Using using() blocks during ADO.NET transaction

Tags: c#, transactions, ado.net

I need to make a relatively trivial transaction which however should affect 5-6 tables so I went throug a several tutorials on how to do this since I've never used transactions before and I eneded up with wrapping each new query in `using(...)` block like this:

```
SqlTransaction transaction = null;
SqlConnection connection = null;
string localConnString =System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager..;
try
{
  connection = new SqlConnection(localConnString);
  connection.Open();

  string insertSomeValues = "some SQL INSERT query"..
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertSomeValues, connection))
  {   
    ..
  }
  using(SqlCommand newCommand = new SqlCommand(otherQuery, connection))
  {
    ..
  }
  transaction.Commit();
}
catch
{
  transaction.Rollback();
}
finally
{
  connection.Close();
}
```

So I hope you got the idea. The problem that I think there is with this implementation is that since the `using` block is in pricatice a `try-catch` block if an exception is thrown somewhere along the way the other code will be still executed, and more important the `transaction.Commit();` too. Which makes the transaction useless since I end up with partially changed `database` when I want a transaction (all or nothing).

Due to my lack of experience on the topic I would like to know what's the way to properly hande those kind of situations. In one of the examples there was a `bool` flag indicating how the current operation went and before calling `transaction.Commit();` there's some sort of check :

```
if (!hasErrors)
{
  transaction.Commit();
}
```

but since I'm including serveral tables in my transaction and I have a some query that are used to fetch information or check for something, the idea of using a flag is not very tempting. I was thinking about removing the `using()` blocks so that (at least I think that is what should happen) whenever an error is thrown I go directly to the main catch block. So .. there are some ideas but what is the actual way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified ur code,by including common transaction for all the commands.

```
SqlTransaction transaction = null;
SqlConnection connection = null;

string localConnString =System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager..;
try
{
 connection = new SqlConnection(localConnString);
 connection.Open();
 transaction=connection.BeginTransaction();
 string insertSomeValues = "some SQL INSERT query"..
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertSomeValues, connection,transaction))
 {   
  ..
 }
 using(SqlCommand newCommand = new SqlCommand(otherQuery, connection,transaction))
 {
  ..
 }
 transaction.Commit();
  }
  catch
 {
  transaction.Rollback();
  }
  finally
  {
    connection.Close();
  }
```